# how to fetch last record for the tranactional table which have multiple records of same id in postgresql with join?

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate

I have two tables one master table named complaints and another transactional table named complaintstaus table.

Below is the main table complaint table

```
| Complaintid | Status | Reopen | Parent_complaint_id |
|-------------|--------|--------|---------------------|
|         102 |      5 |      1 |                 102 |
|         103 |      0 |      0 |                 103 |
|         106 |      3 |      0 |                 106 |
|         154 |      5 |      1 |                 154 |
|         123 |      5 |      1 |                 123 |
|         132 |      5 |      1 |                 132 |
|         167 |      2 |      0 |                 167 |
```

Below is the second table named complaintstatus

```non
| Parent_id | currentstatus | openstatus |
|-----------|---------------|------------|
|       102 |             2 |          0 |
|       102 |             5 |          0 |
|       102 |             5 |          1 |
|       102 |             0 |          0 |
|       103 |             0 |          0 |
|       106 |             3 |          0 |
|       154 |             2 |          0 |
|       154 |             5 |          0 |
|       154 |             5 |          1 |
|       154 |             0 |          0 |
|       123 |             2 |          0 |
|       123 |             5 |          0 |
|       123 |             5 |          1 |
|       123 |             0 |          0 |
|       167 |             2 |          0 |
```

Result should be

```
| Parent_id | currentstatus | openstatus |
|-----------|---------------|------------|
|       102 |             0 |          0 |
|       154 |             0 |          0 |
|       123 |             0 |          0 |
```

The result I need is total number of reopen =4 and pending count= 3

Comment: How is pending count calculated? Is it the cumulative sum of `openstatus` ordered by Parent_id?

Comment: yes i need this count